# Using Activerecord with Redis is giving me an error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, redis

I am just trying to walk through this tutorial

http://jimneath.org/2011/03/24/using-redis-with-ruby-on-rails.html#redis_and_rails

And when I put this code in lib/user.rb or app/models/user.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # follow a user
  def follow!(user)
    @redis.multi do
...
```

I get this error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Could not find table 'users'
    from /Users/jeremysmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activerecord- 3.0.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:295:in `table_structure'
```

Note that @redis is working, and I'm not using sqlite at all, so I'm not sure why it is being referenced.  I do have sqlite included in my Gemfile, but it is nowhere else in my project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would still require a normal sqlite / mysql database to store your users, it's just certain parts that you are storing in redis. Make sure you have the proper migrations and issue a `rake db:migrate`.

I also noticed you used `@redis` instead of `$redis` are you sure that's working as expected?

Comment: I changed it to @redis, because I hate dollar signs!  Thx, didn't notice the sqlite in there.